# How to change the keyboard in Phonegap iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, soft-keyboard

I have making a phonegap app which have text fields in it.

[image]

Problem:- I want to remove the Done button from the keyboard or I want a Event listener of done button. Ether of the things will work for me.

My Problem is similar to [this link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/ykSAuyAaw64)

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove the done button, since Phonegap uses a `UIWebView` to present the UI you will be stuck with keyboard used by the `UIWebView`.

Comment: Can we remove the whole bar and get a normal ios keyboard in place ??

Comment: No, this bar is part of `UIWebView` and can't be removed if you use a toolkit like phonegap.